# Displaying multiple links from a single MySQL field using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have multiple links inserted into a single database field, like so:

```
    +--+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |id| links                                                                    |
    +--+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |1 |http//link1.com< br />http://link2.com< br />http://link3.com/apage.php?id=3|
    +--+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

how can I loop out individual links from that single field and have them displayed on separate lines using php?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Why would you insert multiple links into one column? Why not just do `link_id` and `link_url` and add one row for each entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have queried your table and have a variable containing your example, ie:

```
$links = 'http//link1.com< br />http://link2.com< br />http://link3.com/apage.php?id=3';
```

simply:

```
$links_r = explode('< br />', $links);
foreach ($links_r as $link_s) {
  echo '<a href="' . $link_s . '">' . $link_s . '</a><br />';
}
```

Comment: ...but as others have mentioned you might want to reconsider your db format. definitely better approaches, but i thought i'd answer your question directly regardless.